# title in subplot and xlabel

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

I have written code below to plot to graphs in a window using subplot.
But for labeling, only first subplot is labeled
what should I do?
This problem exists for titling, too.

```
stem(n, h1);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('h1');
subplot(212)
stem(n, h2);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('h2');
```

Comment: You forgot to add `subplot(211)` before `stem(n,h1)` I think.

Comment: correct subplot to `subplot(2,1,2)` before continuing, have seen versions of matlab giving errors on that sort of syntax. Although it should work.
Also add the first subplot as noted by @Divakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you return handles to your figures/axes when you create them, you can tailor each piece by passing that handle as the first argument to a plot modifying function.

So if you did

```
a1 = subplot(2,1,1);
a2 = subplot(2,1,2);
```

you could then do

```
xlabel(a1, 'title here', 'FontSize', 12)
xlabel(a2, 'other title', 'FontWeight', 'bold')
```

or any other label-specific customizations you want.

Answer (score 0):

To create subplots with individual titles - loop through them:

```
Titles= {'Title One' 'Title Two'} 

figure;
for i = 1:2;
    subplot(1,2,i);
    plot(x,y(:,i);
    title(Titles(i));
end
```

Also if you want a *main* Title and X & Y labels over *all* the subplots this code is handy:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel ...but it takes your code an additional ~13 seconds to run.